# How can I create a RegEx for Strings with Tabulator?

Tags: html, .net, regex, string, text

I have an input string/text like this:

```
    <span id="salutation">


            Mister




</span><div class="c"></div>
```

With which pattern can I get the string Mister?

This pattern:

```
string pattern = "<span id=\"salutation\"> (.*) </span>";
```

have no success for me.

Comment: It may depend to your language, but more or less the pattern is `<span id=\"salutation\">\s*(.*?)\s*</span>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm using C#.NET. But if i use this pattern, the compiler says: not expected escapesequence

Comment: You indeed have to escape it properly. Use `"<span id=\"salutation\">\\s*(.*?)\\s*</span>"` or `@"<span id=""salutation"">\s*(.*?)\s*</span>"`

Comment: Thanks a lot dude!

Comment: @mickmackusa I was waiting for a positive response before posting a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct regex is:

```
<span id="salutation">\s*(.*?)\s*</span>
```

which leaves out all the spaces (`\s`) around "Mister".

But, as in some other language, you have to double escape because of the slash:

```
"<span id=\"salutation\">\\s*(.*?)\\s*</span>"
```

In C# you can even use this trick:

```
@"<span id=""salutation"">\s*(.*?)\s*</span>"
```

Anyway, regex are not the best tool for this. Try to use an HTML parser (see [What is the best way to parse html in C#? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)).